# Given $\phi (u)=\sin u, u\in E$, and $f(t)=(t^2,\sqrt{t})$, find an interval $E$ such that $f\circ \phi$ is defined and differentiable on $E$

Tags: vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Given that $\phi (u)=\sin u, u\in E\subset\mathbb{R}$, and
>   $f(t)=(t^2,\sqrt{t}), t\geq 0$, find a suitable interval E such that
>   $f\circ \phi$ is defined and differentiable on E. Apply the Chain Rule to
>   calculate $(f\circ \phi)'(u), u\in E$.

So, I first tried to find $f\circ\phi$ and ended up with $(f\circ\phi)(u)=(\sin^2 u,\sqrt{\sin u})$, am I correct? After that, I don't know how to find the interval $E$ that would make this function defined and differentiable on $E$. How do I find such interval?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(f\circ\phi)(u)=(\sin(u)^2,\sqrt{\sin(u)})$ to be defined, both $(\sin(u))^2$ and $\sqrt{\sin(u)}$ need to be defined. The problem is of course with $\sqrt{\sin(u)}$, which is defined if and only if $\sin(u)\geq0$. Can you find an interval on which $\sin(u)\geq0$? Note that there is more than one correct answer.

Comment: It could be $[0, \pi], [2\pi,3\pi]$, ect. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: I see, thanks! This reasoning also works when I want to find out if a function is 1-1 and smooth, right? Each coordinate function must be 1-1 and smooth.

Comment: That's right again :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!